# C# Close windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am opening up another form when a button is clicked, but can't decide how to close the current form when doing this. This is the code:

```
private void nextSportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Form1.sportsAdded; i++)
    {
        if (Form1.sportOpened == i)
        {
            Form1.IDNumber = Form1.sportIDArray[i];
            OutputForm OutputForm = new OutputForm();
            OutputForm.ShowDialog();
        }

        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling OutputForm.ShowDialog() waits until OutputForm is closed and only then returns to execute further code. You want to use OutputForm.Show() instead.

Note: If "this" is the main form (the first form shown) of your application, closing "this" will terminate the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

first hide current form don't close after open your new form,

```
this.Hide();

Form1.IDNumber = Form1.sportIDArray[i];
OutputForm OutputForm = new OutputForm();
OutputForm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.Hide();` instead of `this.Close();` and using `this.Close();` inside a `for` loop should throw an exception.